# Access rails includes with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, has-many

I have a model called "Match" and a model called "Bet"

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :bets
end
```

And my Model Bet:

```
class Bet < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :match_id, :user_id, :bet 
   ...
   belongs_to :match
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm using the following code to select some matches and user's bets together:

```
@matches = Match.includes(:bets).where("bets.user_id = ? or bets.user_id is NULL", @user.id)
```

How can I access user bets with this query?

Using this does not work:

```
@matches.each do |match| 
    match.bet.bet
    ...
```

How to access bet attribute inside match?

Thanks!!

---

Trying @sevenseacat answer with this code:

```
 @user ||= User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]

  if @user
    @matches = Match.includes(:home_team, :away_team, :bets).where("bets.user_id = ? or bets.user_id is NULL", @user.id) #.group_by{ |match| match.date.strftime("%d/%m/%y")}

    @matches.each do |match| 
      match.bets.each do |bet| 
        bet.bet 
      end 
    end
  end
```

---

I've changed it to match.bets.first (I only have 1 bet for each match_id and user_id so it works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would access each match's bets by doing simply `match.bets` inside your block.

If you wanted to iterate over those bets, use another `each`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Each user can have only one bet for a match. There's a way to user match.bet ??

Comment: By your code, a match still has many bets, but `match.bets` will only contain the correct bets.

Comment: This code is printing Match object, not bets. `@matches.each do |match| 
    match.bets.each do |bet|
        bet.bet
    end          
end`

Comment: That code doesn't print anything. There's more code you're not showing.

Comment: I've added my code to post. I'm using grape gem, so that's the reason it's printing something

Comment: Where is this code? Because that still doesn't output anything.

Comment: I'm using grape gem, that's in /api/api.rb

Comment: Ok, I'm using `match.bets.first` and it's working :) Thanks @sevenseacat

Answer (score 0):

@sevenseacat is right
`@match.bet.each { |bet| bet.attr }` maybe good for you